# Strongly-typed view binding a collection of objects without getting screwed by ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Note: I'm still relatively new to ASP.Net MVC, so I'm *probably* taking the wrong approach here; don't hesitate to say so.

The summary of the issue is that, if I have a view that's strongly-typed to some collection of model objects (say, `IEnumerable<ModelStateTest.Models.DataObject>`), and I have multiple forms on the view - one for each model object in the collection - then posting any one of those forms causes ALL of the forms to reflect the values from the particular object that was edited.

I understand *why* it does this; if you do some server-side validation or processing, and it fails, you don't want to throw away all the user's changes and revert to what was previously stored in the database. What I don't know is how to manage this behavior on a page with forms bound to multiple objects.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates the behavior. If you click any of the "Save" buttons, all three forms then reflect whatever field values were in the form you saved. I'd like for that to *not* happen; I want only the row that was saved to reflect the posted form variables. I only have rough ideas how I might accomplish this, and I don't want to code by coincidence.

**Models\DataObject.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ModelStateTest.Models {
    public class DataObject {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controllers\HomeController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ModelStateTest.Models;

namespace ModelStateTest.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View("Index", new List<DataObject> {
                new DataObject { Field1 = "Obj 1, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 1, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 1, Field 3" },
                new DataObject { Field1 = "Obj 2, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 2, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 2, Field 3" },
                new DataObject { Field1 = "Obj 3, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 3, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 3, Field 3" }
            });
        }

        public ActionResult SaveItem(DataObject obj) {
            return Index();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views\Home\Index.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelStateTest.Models.DataObject>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach (var obj in Model) {
    using (Html.BeginForm("SaveItem", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
        @Html.TextBox("Field1", obj.Field1);
        @Html.TextBox("Field2", obj.Field2);
        @Html.TextBox("Field3", obj.Field3);
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this works, but it's awful. I'm posting it here in hopes that somebody has a better solution. If I do it this way, I essentially have to maintain two sets of form code.

I've added a "primary key" field to DataObject, and I check if that's the item being modified by peeking into Request.QueryString. If it is, I use HTML Helpers. If not, I use plain old input tags. But I can't possibly believe this is the best way to handle it.

**Models\DataObject.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ModelStateTest.Models {
    public class DataObject {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controllers\HomeController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ModelStateTest.Models;

namespace ModelStateTest.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View("Index", new List<DataObject> {
                new DataObject { Key = 1, Field1 = "Obj 1, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 1, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 1, Field 3" },
                new DataObject { Key = 2, Field1 = "Obj 2, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 2, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 2, Field 3" },
                new DataObject { Key = 3, Field1 = "Obj 3, Field 1", Field2 = "Obj 3, Field 2", Field3 = "Obj 3, Field 3" }
            });
        }

        public ActionResult SaveItem(DataObject obj) {
            return Index();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views\Home\Index.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelStateTest.Models.DataObject>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach (string name in Request.Form) {
    <pre>@name = @Request.Form[name]</pre>
}

@foreach (var obj in Model) {
    using (Html.BeginForm("SaveItem", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
        if (Request.QueryString["Key"] == obj.Key.ToString()) {
            @Html.Hidden("Key", obj.Key);
            @Html.TextBox("Field1", obj.Field1);
            @Html.TextBox("Field2", obj.Field2);
            @Html.TextBox("Field3", obj.Field3);
        } else {
            <input type="hidden" name="Key" value="@obj.Key" />
            <input type="text" name="Field1" value="@obj.Field1" />
            <input type="text" name="Field2" value="@obj.Field2" />
            <input type="text" name="Field3" value="@obj.Field3" />
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
}
```